# Event delegation issue with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in Jquery and I am trying to understand how event delegation work.
I am trying this:

```
 $("#32298").on( 'click',function() { // event delegation
        alert("df");
        var imgs = document.getElementById("32298")[0].src;
        alert(imgs);

  });
```

When I click on the image with this Id I get the first alert but it doesn't work the second alert.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Open console and check the error.

Comment: `document.getElementById("32298")[0]` should be `document.getElementById("32298")` considering unique id was provided..

Comment: var imgs = this.src;

Comment: `document.getElementById("32298")[0]` should be `$(this)`.

Comment: and `document.getElementById("32298")[0].src` should be `$(this).attr('src')`.

Comment: Btw, you may wish to consider using id's that start with a letter, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform event delegation then the second argument of the event handler function needs to be a selector to match the element that matches the one you want to be clicked.

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#32290", function(event) {
```

The problem with your code has nothing to do with event delegation. `getElementById` returns a single element (an id must be unique in the document), not a HTML Collection. (Compare with `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` which use the plural *Elements*.) It won't have a `0` property.

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("32298").src;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("32298")`  is just `this`.

Comment: @JeremyThille — That's an alternative way to get the element.

Comment: Why make a redundant dom request?

Comment: @JeremyThille — I'm addressing the specific problems in the question, not pointing out every deviation from best practise in it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. One more thing. Is it possible to get the id of the image when I click on it. Right now I put manually the id like this:  $("#32298").on( 'click',function() ... Could I on image click to get the id store it in a variable and then run the rest of the code: var imgs = document.getElementById(IDVARIABLE).src; Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Look at `this` and `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks. I did this and worked: $('img').click(function() { var id = $(this).attr('id'); alert(id);});

Comment: @Quentin, last time I answered straight to what OP was asking, I got downvoted because I was "not teaching him, and sometimes, answering is not enough, you need to teach too".

Comment: @JeremyThille — I don't have the context for that. That's the sort of comment I'd expect on an answer that gave a chunk of code without any explanation or which left security vulnerabilities in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery, you can simply use the `$(this)` constructor, rather than `document.getElementById()`:

```
$("#32298").on( 'click',function() { 
    alert("df");
    var imgs = $(this).attr('src');
    alert(imgs);
});
```

For what it's worth, this isn't event delegation by the way, it's just an event bound to an element.

If you must use vanilla JS to fetch the `src` attribute, you don't need to pass an index to the returned value of `getElementById()`, since this function returns a DOMObject, not an array. Update as follows:

```
$("#32298").on( 'click',function() {
    alert("df");
    var imgs = document.getElementById("32298").src;
    alert(imgs);
});
```

It's also worth noting that IDs should be unique, so `#32298` should reference a single element in the DOM. I don't know whether it's a typo, but it appears that you may have multiple elements with the same ID (since you use the variable name `imgs` - i.e. plural).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("#32298").click( function() {
  alert("df");
var imgs = $(this).attr('src');
alert(imgs);

});
```